# Typescript generic constraint for child classes

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints, typescript2.0

Using Typescript 2.3.4.

I'm trying to put a generic constraint on a method parameter, like so: `public static FromFactType<T extends  FactCore>() :T`.  `FactCore` is a base class which has three direct descendents: `FactEvent, FactDuration, FactPlain`.  Each of those direct descendents has 15-20 separate children which add new properties.  As an example, `FactEvent` has a child `FactBirth`, so `FactBirth` inherits indirectly from `FactCore`.

However, when I try to pass an instance of `FactBirth` into my method, I get an error: *Type BirthFact cannot be converted to type 'T'*.  The only way I've been able to appease the Typescript compiler is to explicitly list `BirthFact` in the constraint.  I've tried adding the mid-level classes (FactEvent, FactDuration and FactPlain) to the constaint with no luck - same error.

Do I really need to explicitly list all 60+ bottom-level classes in the constraint?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe add some code that will make it possible for us to reproduce your problem? a link to a playground will be the best

Comment: I'm just facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen, unfortunately no.  Never got this resolved.

Comment: Actually, in my case I was accidentally importing a compiled JS file, that was _out of date_. After fixing the import, things started working just fine :| It _should_ definitively work the way you expect, so might be you also had some other issue that caused this.