# TypeScript: Equivalent of C#'s Generic Type Constraint for extending class?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am attempting to write a protected abstract class which can take the subclass type as a type argument in the superclass constructor's method signature.

What I am looking for is similar to C#'s Generic Type Constraint (`where` keyword) so that I can use a child type in a parameter list.

```
//                    where T : <base class name>
BaseAuthController<T> where T : BaseAuthController
```

**Current superclass**

```
export abstract class BaseAuthController {
    protected constructor(
        protected dialogRef:
            //This class shouldn't know about child classes
            MatDialogRef<Child1DialogComponent> |
            MatDialogRef<Child2DialogComponent> |
            MatDialogRef<Child3DialogComponent>
    ) {

    }
}
```

**Current subclass**

```
export class Child1DialogComponent extends BaseAuthController {
    constructor(dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Child1DialogComponent>) {
        super(dialogRef);
    }
}
```

**Ideal superclass**

```
export abstract class BaseAuthController<T> {
    protected constructor(protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<T>) {

    }
}
```

References

- [C# Generic Type Constraint Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)
- [TypeScript Generics Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)
- [Possibly related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45493893/2831961)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might want self-bounded generics:

```
export abstract class BaseAuthController<T extends BaseAuthController<T>> {
  protected constructor(protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<T>) {}
}
```

This behavior is usually accomplished in TypeScript with [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types), but you can't refer to the `this` type in the constructor.  There is an [open issue about this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) but it doesn't look like it will be solved soon.  Luckily, you can still just [do it the way Java does](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106).  And your subclass should just work:

```
export class Child1DialogComponent extends BaseAuthController<Child1DialogComponent> {
  constructor(dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Child1DialogComponent>) {
    super(dialogRef);
  }
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I'm currently trying the approach. This looks very promising. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's fundamentally different in operation, of course, but there's a way to achieve the same result:

```
export abstract class BaseAuthController<T extends SubClass> {
    protected constructor(protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<T>) {

    }
}
```

Combining with unison types means we can specify multiple children:

```
export abstract class BaseAuthController<T extends SubClass1 | SubClass2> {
    protected constructor(protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<T>) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't think this solves the root problem I am trying to get rid of, which is the fact that the parent class then must know about each and every child class